# SQL querying dates between dates in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which I want to perform a query on.

The first table `Events` has a column of events and a column of dates.

```
event       | date  
------------+------------   
"Christmas" | 2019-12-25
"Blue moon" | 2020-05-16    
"Earth day" | 2020-03-26
```

The second table `Periods` has a column with names of periods, and two columns with the start and end dates of the periods.

```
period              | start date  | end date    
--------------------+-------------+-----------
"Shark week"        | 2019-03-20  | 2019-03-27  
"Easter weekend"    | 2020-04-12  | 2020-04-15  
"Ramadan"           | 2020-04-20  | 2020-05-24
```

I want the query to return a list of events and dates from the Events table where the event occurs between the start and end date of any period.

The query would give the following result on the above tables:

```
event       | date      
------------+------------    
"Blue moon" | 2020-05-16    
"Earth day" | 2020-03-26
```

I have limited knowledge of SQL. The best I can do is to query the events table for events that occurred during a single period. Like this:

```
SELECT event, date FROM 'Events' 
WHERE ("2019-03-20" < date) AND (date < "2019-03-27")
```

I have looked at related questions for querying between two dates. The related questions don't cover cases where the dates come from columns of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a `join`:

```
select e.*, p.*
from events e join
     periods p
     on e.date >= p.start_date and e.date <= p.end_date;
```

Comment: Thank you this was much more straightforward than I thought!